# Can I use php code for Windows 8 metro app?

Tags: php, html, xaml, windows-8

Is it possible to use php to program a metro app instead of JS or C#? I would like to do up an app for my photography/repair/design business, and I have programmed my whole site, gallery and my own backend in php + html5 + css3.

I tried using an iFrame, but it doesn't want to load the page; it just shows the php code. Would it be possible to use php instead of JS for the meto app?

I don't wish to reprogram everything in JS (I modified my main site's code and used it as my 'app'), plus I'm almost illiterate at JS, XAML or C#.

Comment: iframes don't magically interpret PHP code; they're just another browser window. PHP code is interpreted by a webserver.

Comment: perhaps you can -- use php-gtk (it is a library for building gui apps using php) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP-GTK and http://gtk.php.net/ and http://gtk.php.net/manual/en/tutorials.installation.windows.php (but keep in mind that it is a very very bad idea)

Comment: I suspect the answer currently is _no_, but projects like [Phalanger](https://phalanger.codeplex.com/) may support it in the future.

Comment: @Amber: Oops, looks like I mixed up the iFrame in html with the iFrame in metro.

Comment: @Shaheer: Nope, doesn't look like it works.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Yeah, might just have to wait it out.

Comment: Just learn C# or something. PHP is a horribly structured language.

Answer (score 3):

No.  HTML/JS, XAML/C# or XAML/C++ are the different ways to create a Metro style app.  Given that, you can use any of your backend code that's exposed as a web service.